# Empty blank page loading when trying to run Flask App

Tags: python, html, flask

Hi this is my test code in python -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('components.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5100)
```

my html code is in components.html -
file structure -

the file is in the same directory in 'templates' folder

[image: file structure]

this is the output once i run the code - [image]

the file is opening a html page when clicking on it, but the python code returns a blank page.

Comment: How EXACTLY are you running this?  From a command line?  From an IDE?  See, it doesn't look for templates in the directory containing the script.  It looks in the CURRENT directory.  If you are in a directory one level up from this and run `python main.py`, that should work.

Comment: I am using Jupyter lab to run the app

Comment: The `css`, `fonts`, and `images` folders should not be inside of `templates`.  The fact that there are requests for images suggests that it is finding your template just fine.  Try moving those three folder up one level.